# Package 'chromium-browser' has no installation candidate

Tags: docker, chromium

I am trying to install the `chrome` browser in a `docker` image with

```
RUN apt-get install chromium-browser
```

but I get the error:

```
Package chromium-browser is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'chromium-browser' has no installation candidate
```

How to correctly install `chromium` in a `docker` image?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I solved it directly downloading Google Chrome

```
# install manually all the missing libraries
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils

# install chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install
```

Answer (score 51):

If you happen to be running a Debian-based image, the package you want is `chromium` (vs `chromium-browser`). So, for such images, this'll take care of it for you:

```
RUN apt-get install chromium -y
```

Comment: Thanks [@revisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13622976) for catching my grammatical error and suggesting adding the `-y` to the `RUN` command!

Comment: what about `chromium-chromedriver`? It says `no installation candidate` as well

Comment: @Superbman Make sure to `apt-get update` first. If that doesn't help, maybe try searching the package listings for the particular flavor/version you're running? E.g. https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages, https://packages.ubuntu.com/, etc.

Comment: I figured what the issue was. It turns out they renamed `chromium-chromedriver` to `chromium-driver`

Comment: That's great @Superbman! Glad you were able to resolve it.  Thanks for sharing the resolution.

Comment: This was a good fix for armbian 22, thank you. Also I used sudo and not RUN for linux.

Comment: You saved my day with this answer , it worked for me after day of struggling , I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Makes my day to hear it was helpful! 

Answer (score 5):

Use the following to install chrome in a docker container:

```
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb --fix-missing; apt-get -fy install`
```

Comment: Your answer has a ` at the end of the second RUN that makes it return an error, but without it everything goes smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Base on provided answers and comment, I was able to solve it with my setup (Jenkins, Docker, Ubuntu) :

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y chromium-driver
```

Thanks @verespej and @Superbman