# Set up selenium debian server

Tags: python, selenium, google-cloud-platform, debian-stretch

I can't understand how to set up and run selenium inside my GCP server with debian 9 stretch.
This is what i made after i created the istance of 600mb RAM:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo apt-get install unzip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install selenium
python main.py
```

and i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/riccardo/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/riccardo/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

**EDIT**: Found solution [here](https://github.com/garywu/google-compute-engine-selenium)

Comment: have you already checked this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co ?

Comment: yes, it is the same