# Getting an error with Chromedriver using docker

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Below are details of the Docker file:

```
FROM python:3
RUN python3 -m pip install robotframework==3.0.4
RUN python3 -m pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.2.0
RUN python3 -m pip install selenium==3.14.0

# Install Chrome for Selenium
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -o /chrome.deb
RUN dpkg -i /chrome.deb || apt-get install -yf
RUN rm /chrome.deb

# Install chromedriver for Selenium
RUN curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/chromedriver_linux64.zip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN unzip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

After that, executed below commands:

```
sudo docker build -t rb/robot-docker
sudo docker run -ti -v /home/Automation:/usr/src/project rb/robot-docker bash
root> cd /usr/src/project
root> robot sample-0-trivial/sample-0-trivial.txt
```

It gives the error message as:
**"WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127"**

Comment: looks like a dependency issue. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co

Comment: It looks like you're installing chromedriver 2.42 which is a very old version of chromedriver. You need to make sure you're getting the correct version of chromedriver.