# AWS Lambda, Selenium, Headless Chrome incompatible with Python 3.8?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.8

We have a Python app that uses selenium, headless chrome on an AWS Lambda.  It worked fine on Python 3.6 and 3.7.  When we upgraded to 3.8 it no longer works and is giving us an error "/opt/chromedriver unexpectedly exited."

Has anyone been able to get a similar configuration running?

Selenium v 3.14
chromedriver 2.43
headless chrome 1.0.55.

Exact Error:
`File "/opt/python/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__    self.service.start()  File "/opt/python/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start    self.assert_process_still_running()  File "/opt/python/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running    raise WebDriverException(selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /opt/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127`

Comment: I'm also on it. As python 3.8 running on Amazon Linux 2 and a different gcc version, I guess it's a compatibility error because i don't see this linked to python directly.

Comment: @Superpassteque Are you saying you're experiencing the same problem, or you've successfully got AWS Lambda, Selenium, Headless Chrome working with python 3.8?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm using chromedriver 87.0.4280.87 (linux64) and headless chrome 1.0.0-57.

Comment: We downgraded the lambda to 3.7 and everything works perfectly.   We upgraded to 3.8 and sure enough it failed.  So something with 3.8 is not happy!

Comment: @DougBower which chromedriver and headless chrome versions are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66594707/9774231

Comment: I think this can be explained by the fact that Python 3.8 runtime is on Amazon Linux 2, but 3.6 and 3.7 - on Amazon Linux 1