# Cannot start Chromium in AWS Lambda container but works locally

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to set up a headless Chromium browser in AWS Lambda using a docker container. My Dockerfile looks like this

```
# Build stage
# ------------
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14 AS builder

RUN yum install -y make

# Install dependencies
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY package*.json .
COPY tsconfig*.json .
RUN npm ci

# build Typescript
COPY . /usr/src
RUN make compile

# Production stage
# ------------
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14

# Install Chrome
COPY docker/google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN yum update -y && yum install google-chrome-stable -y

# /var/task is where Lambda looks for files by default
COPY package*.json /var/task/

# Install production dependencies only
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
RUN npm install --production

# Copy built files from the previous stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/dist /var/task/

CMD ["app.handler"]
```

`google-chrome.repo`

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome - 64-bit
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

I use Node.js and [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) to control the browser.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  dumpio: true,
  headless: true,
  executablePath: config.chromeExecutablePath,
  // all possible options and explanations
  // can be found here https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--headless',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--single-process',
    '--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data',
    '--data-path=/tmp/data-path',
    '--homedir=/tmp',
    '--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir',
  ],
})
```

It works perfectly fine when running the container locally but once I deploy it and run it in Lambda I get errors like this, and the whole thing just timeouts eventually.

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 46: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: See if any solution from this thread helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429877/aws-lambda-container-running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-works-locally-but-not

Comment: Looks like you don't use a proper Lambda handler. The code of your Lambda needs to follow a certain pattern, to allow the AWS Lambda service to execute your Lambda. The error looks like that does not work. In your Dockerfile you set the `CMD` to `app.handler`. Is your Javascript in a file called `app.js` and does it have a function `handler` that handles a "request"? From the code you provided it does not look like it.

Comment: @Jens oh yeah, I didn't post the app.js code but yeah, I have an exported `handler` function there. I tried it locally with lambda-runtime-emulator and everything works properly on my machine

Comment: Did you find a solution? How did you solve it?

Comment: @G.M I didn't, so I had to spawn a standalone pod in kubernetes and run the pupeteer there

Answer (score 0):

A better way is install `chromium-headless` package.

You can check my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78115405/17621956) or check the package source [here](https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/chromium/)