# How to install Google chrome in a docker container

Tags: docker, google-chrome, repository, apt-get

I'm trying to install chrome in a docker container. I execute:

```
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb  # problem here
RUN apt -f install -y
```

The problem is that `dpkg -i` fails because of missing dependencies. In principle this is not a big problem, as the next command should fix this, and indeed it does it when *run interactively* from within the container. But the problem is that when *building* a docker container this error makes the build process to stop:

```
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
root@78b45ab9aa33:/# 
exit
```

How can I overcome this problem? Isn't there a simpler way to install chrome without provoking the dependence problem? I can't find the repository to add so I can run a regular `apg-get install google-chrome`, that is what I'd like to do. In the [google linux repository](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/) they just mention that the "the packages will automatically configure the repository settings necessary". Which is not exactly what I get...

Comment: This might help: https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8

Comment: It does! Thank you.

Comment: Cool, mind to share your Dockerfile with us? There can another person searching for answers :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

After the comment by @Facty and some more search, I found two solutions to install Google Chrome without raising this error. I'll post it below for future references or people having the same issue.

There are actually **two ways** to install Chrome on a docker container:

If you download the *deb file* manually, you can install it with `apt-get` instead of `dpkg`. This will automatically install the dependencies without having to call `apt -f install -y` later :

```
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

The other solution is to add the repositories (installing the gpg key) and install from them directly, skipping the manual download:

```
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \ 
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Both of them gets stuck on "Select a geographical area: " where it asks for a number as input. How to handle that any ideas?

Comment: @YaserSakkaf Add `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive` to the Dockerfile.

Comment: For the first option (installing the deb file) you may also need `apt-get update` prior to installing it - at least this was the case for me.

Answer (score 16):

Here an example for Node versions (debian based)
Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.16.0 as base
# Chrome dependency Instalation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    fonts-liberation \
    libasound2 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libatspi2.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libdrm2 \
    libgbm1 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
#    libgtk-4-1 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libwayland-client0 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxkbcommon0 \
    libxrandr2 \
    xdg-utils \
    libu2f-udev \
    libvulkan1
 # Chrome instalation 
RUN curl -LO  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
# Check chrome version
RUN echo "Chrome: " && google-chrome --version
```

Comment: worked like charm on u20.04. thanks. all other answers here failed.

Comment: I get a ton of errors "requested an impossible situation"

https://gist.github.com/fotoflo/954d68ebcd68c0eeab09283872f21637

Comment: @fotoflo It's look like you took shortcut and do not import "# Chrome dependency Installation" if you will do, the error will gone.

Comment: Even with adding  "# Chrome dependency Installation", the issue remains. When I try to build the image using gcloud submit command, it works fine, however, with Docker, I get the same issue as @fotoflo

Answer (score 5):

If you're using it in Python, to run selenium. Here is what solved my problem.

```
RUN apt -f install -y
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -y
```

Sometimes, using `wget` doesn't solve the problem. Due to lack of support. So you can use `apt -f install -y`

The only mistake @Pythonist had was the disorder of commands.

Comment: So you can instrument Chrome with a desktop-less linux?

Comment: Yes, in the case of deployment on terminal servers like AWS (EC2-Linux), DigitalOcean (droplet-Linux), or GCP (VM), etc. You only have the option to use the system from the terminal. there is no GUI by default, (although you can install GUI, but that slowdowns the instance) only option is to run the selenium without GUI. So you can use this method to use selenium.

Comment: add --fix-missing to the end of the apt-get install command to sort out any missing packages

Answer (score 1):

Note that some base images may have or not have `wget` or `gnupg`,
so full working `Dockerfile` example is

```bash
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update; apt-get clean

# Install wget.
RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN apt-get install -y gnupg

# Set the Chrome repo.
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

# Install Chrome.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Hii, Thanks.

If I wanted to use a particular version of chrome (i.e 114), how do I implement that in the above snippet ?

Comment: Interesting to know - how to test any of these, as in, how do we know if the browser is installed/available? what version is installed?

Answer (score 0):

For selenium, and using the following docker base:

```
FROM python:3.11 as python-base
```

The following worked for me (Needed the --fix-missing) from an answer above.

```
# Install chrome for python selenium
RUN apt -f install -y
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -y --fix-missing
```

Answer (score -5):

`apt-get` won't work.

You should use `dpkg -i ./google-chrome.deb`