# sbt native package manager custom dockerfile:E: Command line option 'O' [from -O] is not understood in combination with the other options

Tags: docker, scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

i have an akka-http project i am using sbt-native package manager for creating a dockerfile for it and i need to add some additional commands in my dockerfile for that i am referring to the example given [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#add-commands)

here i have commands for downloading Chrome in the container

```
    FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update; apt-get clean

# Install wget.
RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN apt-get install -y gnupg

# Set the Chrome repo.
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

# Install Chrome.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

taken [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955307/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-a-docker-container)
here is my code in build.sbt

```
        dockerCommands ++= Seq(
      // setting the run script executable
      ExecCmd("RUN",
    "apt-get",
    "update",
    "apt-get",
    "clean",
    "&&",
    "apt-get",
    "install",
    "-y",
    "wget",
    "&&",
    "apt-get",
    "install",
    "-y",
    "gnupg",
    "&&",
    "wget",
    "-q",
    "-O",
    "-",
    "https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub",
  "|",
    "apt-key add",
    "-",
    "&&",
    "echo",
    "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main",
    ">>",
    "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list",
  "&&",
    "apt-get","update",
    "&&",
    "apt-get",
    "-y",
    "install",
    "google-chrome-stable")
    )
```

and `docker:stage`
creates the following dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
USER root
RUN id -u demiourgos728 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || (( getent group 0 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || ( type groupadd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && groupadd -g 0 root || addgroup -g 0 -S root )) && ( type useradd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && useradd --system --create-home --uid 1001 --gid 0 demiourgos728 || adduser -S -u 1001 -G root demiourgos728 ))
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY --chown=demiourgos728:root opt /opt
EXPOSE 8083
USER 1001:0
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/notary-scraping"]
CMD []
RUN ["apt-get", "update", "apt-get", "clean", "&&", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "wget", "&&", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "gnupg", "&&", "wget", "-q", "-O", "-", "https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub", "|", "apt-key add", "-", "&&", "echo", "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main", ">>", "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list", "&&", "apt-get", "update", "&&", "apt-get", "-y", "install", "google-chrome-stable"]
```

on `docker:pubishLocal` i am getting this exception

```
     info] E: Command line option 'O' [from -O] is not understood in combination with the other options.
[info] Removing intermediate container dc789447c7c0
[error] The command 'apt-get update apt-get clean && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install -y gnupg && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && echo deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable' returned a non-zero code: 100
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 100
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:564)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$37(DockerPlugin.scala:209)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$37$adapted(DockerPlugin.scala:201)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[error] (Docker / publishLocal) Nonzero exit value: 100
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jun 14, 2023, 4:40:10 PM
```

what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You're putting `apt-get install` as a single word in a JSON-syntax command array, so the system is looking for a binary named that, including the space as part of the command filename.  Break it into two words.

Comment: i have edited my answer and fixed that but getting another error

Answer (score 1):

If the commands for downloading Chrome in the container are ok, I guess you are missing a `;` between `apt-get update` and `apt-get clean`. As you already seen, `ExecCmd` receives a list of `String` and each command and parameter of the command must be a different string. That's why you write something like

```scala
ExecCmd("RUN", "apt-get", "update")
```

In your case what you did, was put all the commands in just one `ExecCmd`. Like the following

```scala
dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  ExecCmd("RUN",
    "apt-get", "update", // in `commands for downloading Chrome` you have a `;` but not here
    "apt-get", "clean",
    "&&",
    "apt-get", "install", "-y", "wget",
    "&&",
    // ...
  )
)
```

I think that should solve your issue. Also I suggest to check [what's the difference between semicolon and double ampersand in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187145/whats-the-difference-between-semicolon-and-double-ampersand). Not sure which one is what you need in this case.

Instead of having all the commands together as a `List` of `String`s, maybe you could use one `ExecCmd` per command. In that way, it would be easier to read

```scala
dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  ExecCmd("RUN", "apt-get", "update")
  ExecCmd("apt-get", "clean")
  ExecCmd("apt-get", "install", "-y", "wget")
  // ...
)
```

Another approach here could be create a **docker image** that already has the **chrome installed** and use it as a base image for the one that you are going to use to pack your app. In that way, you don't need to write commands as `String`s inside a `List`.