# sbt docker plugin: Unable to add chrome in dockerfile using ExecCmd

Tags: docker, scala, sbt

i am using [sbt docker plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) to create my image I am trying to add Chrome to my image here is my code taken from [How to install Google chrome in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955307/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-a-docker-container)

build.sbt

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.{DockerChmodType, DockerPermissionStrategy, ExecCmd}

dockerChmodType := DockerChmodType.UserGroupWriteExecute
dockerPermissionStrategy := DockerPermissionStrategy.CopyChown
dockerAdditionalPermissions += (DockerChmodType.UserGroupPlusExecute, "/var/run/")
daemonUserUid in Docker := None
daemonUser in Docker    := "root"
    dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  ExecCmd("RUN", "apt-get", "update","&&","apt-get","install","-y","fonts-liberation","libasound2"
    ,"libatk-bridge2.0-0","libatk1.0-0","libatspi2.0-0","libcups2","libdbus-1-3","libdrm2","libgbm1","libgtk-3-0"
    ,"libgtk-4-1","libnspr4","libnss3","libwayland-client0","libxcomposite1","libxdamage1","libxfixes3","libxkbcommon0"
    ,"libxrandr2","xdg-utils","libu2f-udev","libvulkan1"),
  ExecCmd("RUN", "curl", "-LO","https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"),
  ExecCmd("RUN","apt-get","install","-y","./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"),
  ExecCmd("RUN","rm","google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb")
)
```

i am getting the following exception

```
error] #0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
[error] #1 [internal] load .dockerignore
[error] #1 transferring context: 2B done
[error] #1 DONE 0.0s
[error] #2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
[error] #2 transferring dockerfile: 799B done
[error] #2 DONE 0.0s
[error] #3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8
[error] #3 DONE 0.0s
[error] #4 [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:8
[error] #4 DONE 0.0s
[error] #5 [internal] load build context
[error] #5 transferring context: 21.09MB 0.1s done
[error] #5 DONE 0.2s
[error] #6 [2/7] WORKDIR /opt/docker
[error] #6 CACHED
[error] #7 [3/7] COPY --chown=root:root opt /opt
[error] #7 DONE 0.5s
[error] #8 [4/7] RUN ["apt-get", "update", "&&", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "fonts-liberation", "libasound2", "libatk-bridge2.0-0", "libatk1.0-0", "libatspi2.0-0", "libcups2", "libdbus-1-3", "libdrm2", "libgbm1", "libgtk-3-0", "libgtk-4-1", "libnspr4", "libnss3", "libwayland-client0", "libxcomposite1", "libxdamage1", "libxfixes3", "libxkbcommon0", "libxrandr2", "xdg-utils", "libu2f-udev", "libvulkan1"]
[error] #8 0.380 E: The update command takes no arguments
[error] #8 ERROR: process "apt-get update && apt-get install -y fonts-liberation libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatspi2.0-0 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libdrm2 libgbm1 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-4-1 libnspr4 libnss3 libwayland-client0 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 xdg-utils libu2f-udev libvulkan1" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
[error] ------
[error]  > [4/7] RUN ["apt-get", "update", "&&", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "fonts-liberation", "libasound2", "libatk-bridge2.0-0", "libatk1.0-0", "libatspi2.0-0", "libcups2", "libdbus-1-3", "libdrm2", "libgbm1", "libgtk-3-0", "libgtk-4-1", "libnspr4", "libnss3", "libwayland-client0", "libxcomposite1", "libxdamage1", "libxfixes3", "libxkbcommon0", "libxrandr2", "xdg-utils", "libu2f-udev", "libvulkan1"]:
[error] 0.380 E: The update command takes no arguments
[error] ------
[error] Dockerfile:8
[error] --------------------
[error]    6 |     ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/notary-scraping"]
[error]    7 |     CMD []
[error]    8 | >>> RUN ["apt-get", "update", "&&", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "fonts-liberation", "libasound2", "libatk-bridge2.0-0", "libatk1.0-0", "libatspi2.0-0", "libcups2", "libdbus-1-3", "libdrm2", "libgbm1", "libgtk-3-0", "libgtk-4-1", "libnspr4", "libnss3", "libwayland-client0", "libxcomposite1", "libxdamage1", "libxfixes3", "libxkbcommon0", "libxrandr2", "xdg-utils", "libu2f-udev", "libvulkan1"]
[error]    9 |     RUN ["curl", "-LO", "https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"]
[error]   10 |     RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"]
[error] --------------------
[error] ERROR: failed to solve: process "apt-get update && apt-get install -y fonts-liberation libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatspi2.0-0 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libdrm2 libgbm1 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-4-1 libnspr4 libnss3 libwayland-client0 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 xdg-utils libu2f-udev libvulkan1" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:564)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$37(DockerPlugin.scala:209)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$37$adapted(DockerPlugin.scala:201)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[error] (Docker / publishLocal) Nonzero exit value: 1
[error] Total time: 102 s, completed Sep 8, 2023, 4:55:43 PM
```

here is the generated dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY --chown=root:root opt /opt
EXPOSE 8083
USER root
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/notary-scraping"]
CMD []
RUN ["apt-get", "update", "&&", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "fonts-liberation", "libasound2", "libatk-bridge2.0-0", "libatk1.0-0", "libatspi2.0-0", "libcups2", "libdbus-1-3", "libdrm2", "libgbm1", "libgtk-3-0", "libgtk-4-1", "libnspr4", "libnss3", "libwayland-client0", "libxcomposite1", "libxdamage1", "libxfixes3", "libxkbcommon0", "libxrandr2", "xdg-utils", "libu2f-udev", "libvulkan1"]
RUN ["curl", "-LO", "https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"]
RUN ["rm", "google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"]
```

Comment: Seems like SBT plugin does not handle commands of the form `x && y` as it generates `RUN ["X", "&&", "y"]` where you'd expect `RUN X && y`. Not sure there's anything you can do except open an issue to the SBT plugin, or use multiple commands separately.