# Docker: "webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser"

Tags: python, docker, python-webbrowser

**My Docker configuration:**

```
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY /app .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip &&  \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    rm requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**When I run inside in Docker container:**

```
>>> webbrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')
False

>>> webbrowser._browsers.items()
dict_items([])
```

**When I try locally (MacOS):**

```
>>> webbrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')
True

>>> webbrowser._browsers.items()
dict_items([('macosx', [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x109b965d0>]), ('chrome', [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x109ee3b50>]), ('firefox', [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x109ee3b90>]), ('safari', [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x109ee3c10>])])
```

I tried installing the browser, but the result remained the same.

```
>>> webbrowser.get('chrome')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/webbrowser.py", line 66, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

Comment: A Docker container runs inside an isolated environment (and on MacOS hosts, inside a hidden Linux virtual machine).  It doesn't have access to the host system's desktop environment.  What are you hoping the `webbrowser.open()` call will do?  What leads you to run this code inside a container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm using a library to get a Google Drive token. The library starts a local server where a specific link is called, which should open for the user. After successful user authorization, the local server returns the token and completes its work. [screenshot 1](https://imageupload.io/yYbViCiFxMTukTh) [screenshot 2](https://imageupload.io/VO1dbMUbNeuhoFo) [screenshot 3](https://imageupload.io/QSDrVE3kTiksULb) [screenshot 4](https://imageupload.io/bMPbpTk45XVv69H)

Comment: That seems like your application needs to send back an HTTP redirect to start something like an OAuth flow.  "Start a browser on the machine running the server" won't work if the client and server aren't running on the same system, Docker or otherwise.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't want to modify the library code. I can, of course, inherit the class and make own function that will repeat the one that launches the local server, but with the exception of this launch, simply receive the generated link and send it to the user for openning in the browser.

Is it possible to do this HTTP redirection at the container configuration level?

Comment: No, Docker can't rewrite the application code like this and it doesn't modify things like HTTP responses.

Comment: @DavidMaze Ok, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your container does not have a webbrowser installed so the python class can't find any.

You can try this in dockerfile to get chrome installed on the container

[How to install Google chrome in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955307/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: I saw this example, it didn't help me.  

[link](https://imageupload.io/BVEzwMxZ1O5MwjG)  
[link](https://imageupload.io/6rySD7IeTb5vi4N)