# Selenium with Chrome on JetBrains Datalore

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, google-chrome-headless, datalore

I am trying to test Selenium with headless Chrome on JetBrains Datalore, but am getting an error when trying to create the webdriver. Specifically, I am getting the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chrome/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `chromedriver` needs some extra libraries.
Try this

```
apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0=2.50.3-2 \
    libnss3=2:3.26.2-1.1+deb9u1 \
    libgconf-2-4=3.2.6-4+b1 \
    libfontconfig1=2.11.0-6.7+b1
```

Also there are many existing questions about this error here.
Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co)
And several [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=Service+chrome%2Fchromedriver+unexpectedly+exited.+Status+code+was%3A+127&oq=Service+chrome%2Fchromedriver+unexpectedly+exited.+Status+code+was%3A+127&aqs=chrome..69i57.680j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)