# Is it possible to scrape web sites with python without the browser installed?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am trying to scrape data from a website using python. The problem is: there is no browser installed, and it cannot be installed (it is a pure Debian OS, without the GUI). I was thinking that it might be possible to use a chrome driver and a `headless` mode in selenium, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my test code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  
options = Options()
options.headless = True
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
  
driver.get('https://www.kino-teatr.ru/')

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id('search_input_top')  # find search bar
search_bar.send_keys('Avengers')  # enter the name of the movie
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)  # get the results

page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', class_='list_item')  # find the first item
print(div.find('a')['href'])  # find a link to the page
```

And it gives me the following error

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5606b093c113 <unknown>
#1 0x5606b04046d8 <unknown>
#2 0x5606b04259c9 <unknown>
#3 0x5606b042319a <unknown>
#4 0x5606b045de0a <unknown>
#5 0x5606b0457f53 <unknown>
#6 0x5606b042dbda <unknown>
#7 0x5606b042eca5 <unknown>
#8 0x5606b096d8dd <unknown>
#9 0x5606b0986a9b <unknown>
#10 0x5606b096f6b5 <unknown>
#11 0x5606b0987725 <unknown>
#12 0x5606b096308f <unknown>
#13 0x5606b09a4188 <unknown>
#14 0x5606b09a4308 <unknown>
#15 0x5606b09bea6d <unknown>
#16 0x7f35ddc8bea7 <unknown>
```

I've already tried installing the driver as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911832/9510022) and installing additional libraries as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66166241/9510022), but with no success.

Is it possible to use selenium without the installed browser and what should I do to achieve that?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to [install requests lib](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install) and do the following to get required HTML page:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org'
>>> response = requests.get(url).text
>>> '7 Alternative Career Paths For Software Engineers' in response
True
```

Then you can use [LXML](https://lxml.de/parsing.html) or [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the page

UPDATE

```
from lxml import html

response = requests.post('https://www.kino-teatr.ru/search/', data={'text':'мстители'.encode('cp1251')}).content
doc = html.fromstring(response)
entries = doc.xpath('//div[@class="list_item_name"]/h4')
first_movie = entries[0].text_content()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But, if I am not mistaken, `requests` does not support dynamic web pages. That is why I was trying to use `selenium`

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi What is your goal? do you want to get HTML doc or get specific (dynamic) data from page?

Comment: The code above is just a test code. In the future, I want to find specific data on dynamic pages. I also need to use selenium's `send_keys` method

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi almost everything that you do on web-page (except executing JavaScript) is just sending HTTP-requests. Even if you need to fill the form and then press on submit button on page you can do the same with python-requests. So called "dynamic data" comes from XHR that can be simulated by python-requests. So instead of strictly sticking to Selenium you need to describe your exact issue and I'm quite sure that you can solve it with requests

Comment: Ok, I edited the question with a better example. There is a website `kino-teatr.ru`, where I need to 1) enter a movie name into the search box, and 2) find the link to the first  movie that appears in the results

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi you need to send POST request e.g. `response = requests.post('https://www.kino-teatr.ru/search/', data={'text':'RING'}).text` (pass name to `'text'`),then you can check `'После просмотра некой загадочной видеокассеты следует телефонный звонок и каждый просмотревший умирает. Жертве дается лишь одна неделя, а дальше следует неминуемая смерть.' in response` or `'Палач и жертва' in response` to see that your request returns you the list of founded movies. You can replace `.text` with `.content` to get HTML-doc and parse it with any HTML-parser (like suggested LXML or BeautifulSoup)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it does not seem to work with non-English movies:( For example `requests.post('https://www.kino-teatr.ru/search/', data={'text':'мстители'}).text` returns me a page saying that nothing was found. Is there maybe another parameter for language? And, by the way, where do I find what key-value pairs `data` parameter should contain?

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi seem to be encoding issue. Try `requests.post('https://www.kino-teatr.ru/search/', data={'text':'мстители'.encode('cp1251')}).text`

Comment: Omg, it worked! Finally! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to understand it better, how do you know what key-value pairs should go to `data` parameter?

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi to check how HTTP-request looks like: in Browser press F12 -> switch to Network tab -> do whatever you need on page -> check sent requests. If F12 doesn't work - do right click -> select "Inspect (Q)". Also check updated answer - I've added LXML parsing part

Comment: Got it, thanks!