# How to get the code from Inspect on a website in Python (dynamic content different from source code)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, dynamic

When I try to get the source code for a website, I would usually use `urllib.request.urlopen(url)`. However, when I try to do it for a website with a table (that I believe generated after javascript code is run), it does not return the same as what I see when I press `inspect` on a website.

How can I get what I see in `inspect` *after* the page is loaded?

I have tried using `json` backage and load the page using `json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(url))`, I would get an error:

[image]

I also tried to use selenium Webdriver, but when I call `webdrive.Chrome()` an error is generated:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

How can I fix either of these solutions? Or is there a better solution? Any help would be appeciated.

I'm using replit if that matters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49323099 for the 127 error. can you share the site and include which table you're trying to get? there might be an API alternative or some data buried in `script` tags in the source code

Comment: @Driftr95 I saw this post. I don't think I can run those terminal commands since I'm using replit though. 

This is the [site](https://data.eastmoney.com/stock/tradedetail/2023-01-13.html) I'm using (It's in Chinese, but there is only one table so it should be clear which one I'm referring to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in the [network logs](https://support.happyfox.com/kb/article/882-accessing-the-browser-console-and-network-logs/), the site seems to be using an [API to load the contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8balI.png) of the table. If you copy the API URL and break down the query:

```py
# from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
apiUrl = 'https://datacenter-web.eastmoney.com/api/data/v1/get?callback=jQuery112309834864079678796_1673633495739&sortColumns=SECURITY_CODE%2CTRADE_DATE&sortTypes=1%2C-1&pageSize=50&pageNumber=1&reportName=RPT_DAILYBILLBOARD_DETAILSNEW&columns=SECURITY_CODE%2CSECUCODE%2CSECURITY_NAME_ABBR%2CTRADE_DATE%2CEXPLAIN%2CCLOSE_PRICE%2CCHANGE_RATE%2CBILLBOARD_NET_AMT%2CBILLBOARD_BUY_AMT%2CBILLBOARD_SELL_AMT%2CBILLBOARD_DEAL_AMT%2CACCUM_AMOUNT%2CDEAL_NET_RATIO%2CDEAL_AMOUNT_RATIO%2CTURNOVERRATE%2CFREE_MARKET_CAP%2CEXPLANATION%2CD1_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE%2CD2_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE%2CD5_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE%2CD10_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE%2CSECURITY_TYPE_CODE&source=WEB&client=WEB&filter=(TRADE_DATE%3C%3D%272023-01-13%27)(TRADE_DATE%3E%3D%272023-01-13%27)'
dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(url).query))
```

you can see the parameters

```py
{'callback': 'jQuery112309834864079678796_1673633495739',
 'sortColumns': 'SECURITY_CODE,TRADE_DATE',
 'sortTypes': '1,-1',
 'pageSize': '50',
 'pageNumber': '1',
 'reportName': 'RPT_DAILYBILLBOARD_DETAILSNEW',
 'columns': 'SECURITY_CODE,SECUCODE,SECURITY_NAME_ABBR,TRADE_DATE,EXPLAIN,CLOSE_PRICE,CHANGE_RATE,BILLBOARD_NET_AMT,BILLBOARD_BUY_AMT,BILLBOARD_SELL_AMT,BILLBOARD_DEAL_AMT,ACCUM_AMOUNT,DEAL_NET_RATIO,DEAL_AMOUNT_RATIO,TURNOVERRATE,FREE_MARKET_CAP,EXPLANATION,D1_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE,D2_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE,D5_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE,D10_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE,SECURITY_TYPE_CODE',
 'source': 'WEB',
 'client': 'WEB',
 'filter': "(TRADE_DATE<='2023-01-13')(TRADE_DATE>='2023-01-13')"}
```

<sup>(Btw, from looking the [request's initiator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MaWe.png), the [tradedetail](https://data.eastmoney.com/newstatic/js/lhb/tradedetail.js) script seems to be mostly responsible for generating the parameters.)</sup>

---

You can reform the link

```py
start, end, pgSize, pgNum = '2023-01-13', '2023-01-13', 50, 1
auQstr = 'sortColumns=SECURITY_CODE%2CTRADE_DATE&sortTypes=1%2C-1'
auQstr += f'&pageSize={pgSize}&pageNumber={pgNum}' ## max pageSize seems to be 500
auQstr += '&reportName=RPT_DAILYBILLBOARD_DETAILSNEW&columns=SECURITY_CODE%2CSECUCODE%2CSECURITY_NAME_ABBR%2CTRADE_DATE%2CEXPLAIN%2CCLOSE_PRICE%2CCHANGE_RATE%2CBILLBOARD_NET_AMT%2CBILLBOARD_BUY_AMT%2CBILLBOARD_SELL_AMT%2CBILLBOARD_DEAL_AMT%2CACCUM_AMOUNT%2CDEAL_NET_RATIO%2CDEAL_AMOUNT_RATIO%2CTURNOVERRATE%2CFREE_MARKET_CAP%2CEXPLANATION%2CD1_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE%2CD2_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE%2CD5_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE%2CD10_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE%2CSECURITY_TYPE_CODE&source=WEB&client=WEB'
auQstr += f'&filter=(TRADE_DATE%3C%3D%27{end}%27)(TRADE_DATE%3E%3D%27{start}%27)'
apiUrl = f'https://datacenter-web.eastmoney.com/api/data/v1/get?{auQstr}'
```

and retrieve table data with

```py
# import requests, json, pandas

apiReq = requests.get(apiUrl)
# print(apiReq.status_code, apiReq.reason, 'from', apiReq.url)
# apiReq.raise_for_status()

jDict = {}
try: jDict = json.loads(apiReq.text.strip().strip('jQuery_(0123456789);'))
except: print('failed to extract JSON from', apiReq.text)
rDict =  jDict.get('result') if hasattr(jDict.get('result', {}), 'get') else {}
# for k, v in jDict.items(): print(f'{k}:', type(v) if hasattr(v, 'pop') else v)
# for k, v in rDict.items(): print(f'result_{k}:', type(v) if hasattr(v, 'pop') else v)
```

[I couldn't quite figure out how to generate the `callback` parameter, but I don't see any difference in the data returned either way except that with the callback, the response is wrapped like `{callback}({JSON});` (that's why I added the *`.strip('jQuery_(0123456789);')`* part).]

---

Now `pandas.DataFrame(rDict.get('data', []))` should return a DataFrame that looks like

|  | SECURITY_CODE | SECUCODE | SECURITY_NAME_ABBR | TRADE_DATE | EXPLAIN | CLOSE_PRICE | CHANGE_RATE | BILLBOARD_NET_AMT | BILLBOARD_BUY_AMT | BILLBOARD_SELL_AMT | BILLBOARD_DEAL_AMT | ACCUM_AMOUNT | DEAL_NET_RATIO | DEAL_AMOUNT_RATIO | TURNOVERRATE | FREE_MARKET_CAP | EXPLANATION | D1_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE | D2_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE | D5_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE | D10_CLOSE_ADJCHRATE | SECURITY_TYPE_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 000670 | 000670.SZ | 盈方微 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 实力游资买入，成功率36.52% | 8.61 | 9.9617 | 107855670.84 | 151940017.84 | 44084347.0 | 196024364.84 | 728666824 | 14.801781457255 | 26.901782595773 | 14.2053 | 5250783634.32 | 日涨幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 1 | 000716 | 000716.SZ | 黑芝麻 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 2家机构卖出，成功率35.42% | 9.66 | -9.972 | -83920955.05 | 126116524.26 | 210037479.31 | 336154003.57 | 1793050068 | -4.680346441391 | 18.747608311069 | 26.4683 | 6722651062.26 | 日跌幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 2 | 001298 | 001298.SZ | 好上好 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 2家机构买入，成功率29.10% | 46.97 | 1.8872 | -11553872.19 | 45951665.33 | 57505537.52 | 103457202.85 | 617385681 | -1.871418878923 | 16.757305203844 | 54.3025 | 1127280000.0 | 日换手率达到20%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 3 | 002043 | 002043.SZ | 兔宝宝 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 2家机构卖出，成功率38.08% | 16.6 | -1.7751 | -72462039.78 | 212188958.86 | 284650998.64 | 496839957.5 | 3192972469 | -2.269422629964 | 15.560420965847 | 25.9004 | 11509797762.6 | 日振幅值达到15%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 4 | 002137 | 002137.SZ | 实益达 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 主力做T，成功率27.11% | 9.18 | 3.9638 | 211445.689999998 | 84152129.0 | 83940683.31 | 168092812.31 | 1478965892 | 0.014296860471 | 11.36556381856 | 40.9845 | 3585402921.06 | 日换手率达到20%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 5 | 002186 | 002186.SZ | 全聚德 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 西藏自治区资金卖出，成功率29.46% | 16.84 | -9.9947 | 3151181.58999997 | 188737402.17 | 185586220.58 | 374323622.75 | 2312764542 | 0.136251725274 | 16.185115948998 | 19.3857 | 5187624392.2 | 连续三个交易日内，跌幅偏离值累计达到20%的证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 6 | 002186 | 002186.SZ | 全聚德 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 西藏自治区资金卖出，成功率42.54% | 16.84 | -9.9947 | 10443891.72 | 109080186.16 | 98636294.44 | 207716480.6 | 1031412946 | 1.012581019126 | 20.139022047916 | 19.3857 | 5187624392.2 | 日跌幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 7 | 002217 | 002217.SZ | 合力泰 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 实力游资买入，成功率36.62% | 3.05 | 10.1083 | 31285483.89 | 93345048.93 | 62059565.04 | 155404613.97 | 703558435 | 4.446749883682 | 22.088373365888 | 5.6364 | 9483332520.55 | 连续三个交易日内，涨幅偏离值累计达到20%的证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 8 | 002235 | 002235.SZ | 安妮股份 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 西藏自治区资金买入，成功率36.04% | 9.65 | 1.5789 | -49174252.39 | 182992053.05 | 232166305.44 | 415158358.49 | 2127085536 | -2.311813585197 | 19.51770868936 | 40.3385 | 5290486577.15 | 日换手率达到20%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 9 | 002238 | 002238.SZ | 天威视讯 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 买一主买，成功率39.94% | 9.79 | 10.0 | 13041066.65 | 67516644.74 | 54475578.09 | 121992222.83 | 620322941 | 2.102302814882 | 19.665921533281 | 2.7782 | 7857054176.4 | 连续三个交易日内，涨幅偏离值累计达到20%的证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 10 | 002400 | 002400.SZ | 省广集团 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 主力做T，成功率41.83% | 4.86 | 9.9548 | 66233347.48 | 123818180.47 | 57584832.99 | 181403013.46 | 525010338 | 12.615627290753 | 34.552274561115 | 6.649 | 8199738933.66 | 日涨幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 11 | 002467 | 002467.SZ | 二六三 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 买一主买，成功率38.07% | 6.39 | 9.9828 | 113801422.15 | 251184968.9 | 137383546.75 | 388568515.65 | 2283893105 | 4.982782333414 | 17.013428290463 | 27.1756 | 8680735917.36 | 日涨幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 12 | 002528 | 002528.SZ | 英飞拓 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 浙江资金卖出，成功率34.64% | 11.46 | -9.9764 | -129544714.79 | 108721495.94 | 238266210.73 | 346987706.67 | 1542451167 | -8.398626650979 | 22.495863343595 | 12.7112 | 11992193816.46 | 日跌幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 13 | 002560 | 002560.SZ | 通达股份 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 浙江资金买入，成功率19.33% | 8.81 | 9.9875 | 17471183.83 | 81321592.83 | 63850409.0 | 145172001.83 | 510096412 | 3.425074832716 | 28.45971828361 | 9.977 | 3965177506.62 | 连续三个交易日内，涨幅偏离值累计达到20%的证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 14 | 002576 | 002576.SZ | 通达动力 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 2家机构买入，成功率21.82% | 22.5 | 5.2878 | -19311555.5 | 128003798.4 | 147315353.9 | 275319152.3 | 1422318096 | -1.35775221832 | 19.357073011606 | 37.9045 | 3642812347.5 | 日换手率达到20%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 15 | 002762 | 002762.SZ | 金发拉比 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 买一主买，成功率46.74% | 12.24 | 9.973 | 4698244.86 | 98721360.44 | 94023115.58 | 192744476.02 | 870220454 | 0.539891338845 | 22.148925037793 | 36.1724 | 2461689167.04 | 日涨幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 16 | 002820 | 002820.SZ | 桂发祥 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 3家机构卖出，成功率28.18% | 13.32 | -10.0 | -29093337.0 | 42460011.96 | 71553348.96 | 114013360.92 | 647947778 | -4.490074352875 | 17.596072521758 | 23.1511 | 2668469898.96 | 日跌幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 17 | 002875 | 002875.SZ | 安奈儿 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 主力做T，成功率9.32% | 24.78 | -9.9891 | -83358448.31 | 50606666.78 | 133965115.09 | 184571781.87 | 801943994 | -10.394547366608 | 23.015545131697 | 25.6788 | 3034961970.6 | 日跌幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 18 | 003027 | 003027.SZ | 同兴环保 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 主力做T，成功率18.30% | 32.86 | 10.01 | 41802137.99 | 162093207.65 | 120291069.66 | 282384277.31 | 866481721 | 4.824353125621 | 32.589755844371 | 40.7896 | 2192047882.0 | 日涨幅偏离值达到7%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 19 | 003027 | 003027.SZ | 同兴环保 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 主力做T，成功率18.30% | 32.86 | 10.01 | 41802137.99 | 162093207.65 | 120291069.66 | 282384277.31 | 866481721 | 4.824353125621 | 32.589755844371 | 40.7896 | 2192047882.0 | 日换手率达到20%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 20 | 300492 | 300492.SZ | 华图山鼎 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 实力游资买入，成功率48.81% | 43.33 | 19.9945 | 1105052.6 | 23053326.1 | 21948273.5 | 45001599.6 | 114661901 | 0.963748717196 | 39.247212201723 | 1.9942 | 6087278745.1 | 日涨幅达到15%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 21 | 301297 | 301297.SZ | 富乐德 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 主力做T，成功率2.22% | 18.32 | 0.3286 | -9034857.31 | 29853155.71 | 38888013.02 | 68741168.73 | 546884177 | -1.652060470932 | 12.569602782638 | 41.8968 | 1284169107.44 | 日换手率达到30%的前5只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 22 | 600523 | 600523.SH | 贵航股份 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 普通席位卖出，成功率42.68% | 15.81 | -10.0171 | -28207457.6 | 13579393.0 | 41786850.6 | 55366243.6 | 85000595 | -33.185011940211 | 65.136301222362 | 0.9341 | 6387945442.2 | 非ST、*ST和S证券连续三个交易日内收盘价格跌幅偏离值累计达到20%的证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 23 | 600523 | 600523.SH | 贵航股份 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 普通席位卖出，成功率33.77% | 15.81 | -10.0171 | -16835436.6 | 12407688.0 | 29243124.6 | 41650812.6 | 59671683 | -28.213443552447 | 69.799962907029 | 0.9341 | 6387945442.2 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格跌幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 24 | 600532 | 600532.SH | *ST未来 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 普通席位卖出，成功率28.62% | 9.74 | -4.9756 | -24439826.67 | 40681630.15 | 65121456.82 | 105803086.97 | 409474673 | -5.968580789367 | 25.838737764863 | 2.2835 | 5026480112.8 | ST、*ST和S证券连续三个交易日内收盘价格跌幅偏离值累计达到15%的证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 25 | 600705 | 600705.SH | 中航产融 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 实力游资买入，成功率54.14% | 3.73 | 10.0295 | 73958025.45 | 133172433.75 | 59214408.3 | 192386842.05 | 686213131 | 10.777704784259 | 28.036018746776 | 2.1765 | 32840504627.09 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格涨幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 26 | 600936 | 600936.SH | 广西广电 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 买一主买，成功率41.53% | 4.24 | 10.1299 | 26749602.16 | 54209533.16 | 27459931.0 | 81669464.16 | 143394358 | 18.654570886255 | 56.954447370935 | 2.0507 | 7085151253.36 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格涨幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 27 | 601136 | 601136.SH | 首创证券 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 实力游资买入，成功率30.50% | 17.78 | 0.3953 | -93721279.84 | 97104768.64 | 190826048.48 | 287930817.12 | 1841283839 | -5.089996330544 | 15.637503084607 | 38.2112 | 4859874964.0 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日换手率达到20%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 28 | 603177 | 603177.SH | 德创环保 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 实力游资卖出，成功率49.47% | 15.64 | -10.0115 | -4465384.0 | 21174031.0 | 25639415.0 | 46813446.0 | 150194462 | -2.973068341228 | 31.168556667555 | 4.6327 | 3159280000.0 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格跌幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 29 | 603180 | 603180.SH | 金牌厨柜 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 1家机构买入，成功率50.16% | 36.25 | 10.0152 | 12202253.1 | 26500648.8 | 14298395.7 | 40799044.5 | 87351411 | 13.969153972796 | 46.706795039636 | 1.61 | 5591811972.5 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格涨幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 30 | 603595 | 603595.SH | 东尼电子 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 2家机构卖出，成功率46.97% | 74.61 | -7.6495 | -7432379.62000001 | 121505577.32 | 128937956.94 | 250443534.26 | 1050225268 | -0.707693848783 | 23.846649084813 | 7.496 | 13492188210.51 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格跌幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 31 | 603633 | 603633.SH | 徕木股份 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 1家机构卖出，成功率37.31% | 12.55 | -9.2552 | -73231606.97 | 86340428.24 | 159572035.21 | 245912463.45 | 290563460 | -25.203309105006 | 84.632962262357 | 7.0615 | 4120365975.7 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格跌幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 32 | 603718 | 603718.SH | 海利生物 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 1家机构买入，成功率42.60% | 10.87 | 10.0202 | 20370152.3 | 37268339.3 | 16898187.0 | 54166526.3 | 144941266 | 14.054073668709 | 37.371362756001 | 2.1191 | 7000280000.0 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格涨幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 33 | 603818 | 603818.SH | 曲美家居 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 1家机构买入，成功率42.58% | 7.22 | 10.061 | 5939930.2 | 66439130.2 | 60499200.0 | 126938330.2 | 304253824 | 1.952294344869 | 41.721194669356 | 7.4088 | 4190455842.12 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格涨幅偏离值达到7%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 34 | 605289 | 605289.SH | 罗曼股份 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 1家机构买入，成功率44.60% | 29.99 | 4.6771 | 30283104.67 | 69216892.67 | 38933788.0 | 108150680.67 | 344547940 | 8.789228189842 | 31.389153181412 | 22.4486 | 1517793900.0 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日换手率达到20%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 35 | 688176 | 688176.SH | 亚虹医药 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 3家机构买入，成功率42.03% | 14.42 | 14.2631 | 82667412.7 | 260600938.14 | 177933525.44 | 438534463.58 | 992180700 | 8.331890823919 | 44.199052005345 | 13.6847 | 3371945228.96 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的连续3个交易日内收盘价格涨幅偏离值累计达到30%的证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 36 | 688338 | 688338.SH | 赛科希德 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 1家机构买入，成功率55.14% | 41.8 | 16.8904 | 35149627.58 | 52194475.91 | 17044848.33 | 69239324.24 | 175305000 | 20.050556219161 | 39.496491394997 | 8.9712 | 2047768498.6 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格涨幅达到15%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |
| 37 | 688506 | 688506.SH | 百利天恒 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 4家机构买入，成功率43.76% | 48.45 | 16.747 | 45177674.84 | 82744533.6 | 37566858.76 | 120311392.36 | 272655300 | 16.569520137698 | 44.125822003093 | 17.9553 | 1601916788.1 | 有价格涨跌幅限制的日收盘价格涨幅达到15%的前五只证券 |  |  |  |  | 058001001 |

<sup>The table above was printed with *`print(pandas.DataFrame(rDict.get('data', [])).to_markdown(disable_numparse=True))`*.</sup>