# How can I use ChromeDriverManager().install() when deploying to fly.io

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdeploy

I have a questions bothering me for weeks.
I am deploying a web-scratching website to fly.io. The testing at my local notebook is OK without mistake.
But when I deploying it to fly.io, it will turn out some error. Following information are my code and the error showed on fly.io. Thanks a lot!

Code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions  
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get("http://example.com")
```

ERROR from fly.io:

```
2023-02-18T08:23:40.866 app\[e911729f\] nrt \[info\] raise WebDriverException()

2023-02-18T08:23:40.866 app\[e911729f\] nrt \[info\] selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/cnb/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/110.0.5481.77/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Comment: What is OS of your local and what is OS of where fly.io is running on? Looks like they are different OS. Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co