# Unable to launch Selenium, encountering DeprecationWarning and WebDriverException errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Suddenly today, Selenium could not be launched in my project. The error messages are as follows:

```
main.py:11: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='drivers/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/app/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='drivers/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service drivers/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255
```

The settings of my Dockerfile are as follows:

```
FROM python:3.10-buster

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl unzip gettext python-babel \
    ffmpeg \
    poppler-utils \
    fonts-takao-* fonts-wqy-microhei fonts-unfonts-core

# Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install \
    && rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
# Download and extract the latest version of ChromeDriver
RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(curl -sL "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE") && \
    curl -sL "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip" > chromedriver.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver.zip -d /usr/local/bin && \
    rm chromedriver.zip


# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set and move to APP_HOME
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ENV PYTHONPATH $APP_HOME
# Copy local code to the container image
COPY . .
```

requirements.txt

```
selenium==4.15.1
```

And, I created a simple `main.py` to just launch Selenium.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print(driver.title) 

driver.quit()
```

### What I did

I downloaded the drivers of version 119 and 120 from this link, set them in `executable_path`, and executed it, but the same error was returned.
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Please help me!

### Environment

MacOS 13.6
Apple M2
Docker desktop 4.21.1

Comment: What is your selenium version?

Comment: My selenium version is 4.15.1

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Selenium 4 `executable_path` is deprecated you have to use an instance of the `Service()` class with `ChromeDriverManager().install()`

> - Deprecate all but `Options` and `Service` arguments in driver instantiation. (#9125,#9128)

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d6acda7c0254f9681574bf4078ff2001705bf940/py/CHANGES#L101

You can try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.your_website_.com")
```

---

Edit: After looking at your example I think you can try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
service = Service(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")   # your path to chromedriver executable file
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print(driver.title) 

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you. I change the driver path and run your second code. But I got same error.

Comment: You're welcome .. did you get `DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated` on executing the above codes as well?

Comment: The message is no longer displayed. I'm still seeing the `Message: Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255` and Chrome fails to start.

Comment: It seems `chromedriver` needs some extra libraries.

Comment: Please see the answers of this question. Hopefully it will solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co

Comment: My environment complicated the problem. There seems to be an issue with Macs with ARM architecture. The error no longer occurs when I run the code suggested on GitHub CodeSpace.

Comment: Oh I see.... great to know that your error disappears.