# Selenium webdriver giving errors

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have been getting error 127 when running my code for the past 2 days. It is running on a linux server, I am running it on bot-hosting.net.

```
File "/home/container/bot.py", line 41, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
super().__init__(
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/container/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

I have tried doing apt-get (libraries), but I don't have root access. If this is the only way to fix it i'd have to talk with the developers of bot.hosting-net

This is the code which handles the webdriver:

```
extension_path = r'/home/container/jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhg/3.2.0_0'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--load-extension={extension_path}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--headless=new')
chrome_options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=home\container\Google for Testing\User Data')

service = Service(executable_path=r'/home/container/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver')
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Mismatched Chromedriver version: Ensure that the version of Chromedriver you are using is compatible with your Chrome browser. Try updating Chromedriver or using a version that matches your Chrome version.

2.Chromedriver not installed or incorrect path: Make sure Chromedriver is installed correctly, and its path is set correctly. Your error message indicates that the Chromedriver path is /home/container/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver. Ensure that the file at this path exists and has execution permissions.

```
chmod +x /home/container/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver
```

3.Chromedriver dependency issues: Chromedriver depends on certain system libraries. You may need to install these libraries, depending on your operating system. For example, on Ubuntu, you can use the following commands to install some potentially required libraries:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libnss3 libgconf-2-4 libfontconfig1
```

File permission issues: Ensure that the Chromedriver executable has sufficient permissions. You can grant execution permissions using the following command:

5.Check for additional error messages: In the error message, there may be additional details about Chromedriver's unexpected exit. Try examining the complete error message to see if it provides more clues.

By checking these aspects, you should be able to identify the cause of Chromedriver's unexpected exit and resolve the issue.

Comment: Okay so for step 1. I only have a chromedriver installed. I have never installed something else like chromium-browse etc. (I don't know if I can do that on this host). For 2. I executed it and it worked no errors. For 3. I installed the libraries but they are in /home/container now, where do I put the files? for 5. What can I do to hunt the error down. I have tried changing, deleting and adding lines, they all return to error 127.

Comment: @Maikelvdberg you should install chromiun-browse, please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co)

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541)

Comment: @Tououououer, I got the exact same status 127 error. my chrome version is 119.0.6045.159, chromedriver version is 119.0.6045.105, is this ok? how compatibility works? does chrome and chromedriver need to exact same version number?thx

Comment: @ErikJohnsson, "my chrome version is 119.0.6045.159, chromedriver version is 119.0.6045.105." i think that is ok, How are you sure? It's still not correct. I really can't determine what the problem is. You can view my repository [carp](https://github.com/weiensong/carp)