# Installing ChromeDriver and Headless Chrome Driver with latest version of Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `Python` and `Selenium` on `AWS Lambdas` for crawling.
I have updated `Python` to 3.11 and `Selenium` to 4.18.0, but then my crawlers stopped working.
This is the code for `Selenium`:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def get_headless_driver():
    options = Options()
    service = Service(executable_path=r'/opt/chromedriver')
    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

    return webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)


def get_selenium_driver():
    return get_local_driver() if os.environ.get('STAGE') == 'local' else get_headless_driver()
```

This is the code for installing `chromedriver`:

```
#! /bin/bash

# exit when any command fails
set -e

NOCOLOR='\033[0m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'

echo -e "\n${GREEN}Installing 'headless' layer dependencies...${NOCOLOR}\n"
sudo mkdir -p layers/headless && sudo chmod 777 layers/headless && cd layers/headless

# https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/issues/133
echo -e "\n${GREEN}Installing Chrome Driver v2.37...${NOCOLOR}\n"
sudo curl -SL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip > chromedriver.zip
sudo chmod 755 chromedriver.zip
sudo unzip chromedriver.zip
sudo rm chromedriver.zip

echo -e "\n${GREEN}Installing Serverless Chrome v1.0.0-37...${NOCOLOR}\n"
sudo curl -SL https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-41/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip > headless-chromium.zip
sudo chmod 755 headless-chromium.zip
sudo unzip headless-chromium.zip
sudo rm headless-chromium.zip

cd ../../
```

I am getting this error:

```
Message: Service /opt/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

How should I fix this error?
Should I also update the chromedriver and headless?
What versions should I chose?

Answer (score 0):

As of Selenium 4.6+, you no longer need to install, setup, or otherwise manage drivers yourself because they added [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager) to Selenium. Delete all the drivers off your machine, remove all the extra code when creating Chrome driver (see the docs), and then run your script and Selenium will automatically download and install the driver and then use the newest driver in the run.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly missing libraries. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710327/7058266 which was about solving `Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127`.

You can also try https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase, which includes optimized Selenium configuration to work on various environments. It also has methods to simplify your test scripts:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
try:
    driver.open("https://seleniumbase.io/simple/login")
    driver.type("#username", "demo_user")
    driver.type("#password", "secret_pass")
    driver.click('a:contains("Sign in")')
    driver.assert_exact_text("Welcome!", "h1")
    driver.assert_element("img#image1")
    driver.highlight("#image1")
    driver.click_link("Sign out")
    driver.assert_text("signed out", "#top_message")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```