# "WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally" when trying to run .side file on command line using selenium-side-runner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-side-runner

I used Selenium in my Chrome browser and recorded a series of steps. It works great in the browser. I want to get it to run automatically once per day, so I thought I'd try to get it to run from the command line so that I can put it in a crontab.

I did some googling and installed selenium-side-runner. I am trying to run the file from my terminal using "selenium-side-runner script.side".

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
      (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

      at Object.throwDecodedError (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:524:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:601:13)
      at Executor.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:529:28)
```

What can I try to do to fix this error? Or is there another way I can get this to run daily using the chrome extension and not using the command line?

After getting the error, I did more searching and tried adding these options to the .side file, but it didn't fix the issue:

```
 "environments": [
    {
      "id": "chrome",
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "chromeOptions": {
            "binary": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
          }
        },{
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        "args": ["--no-sandbox","--headless"]
      }}
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `--no-sandbox` argument unless you are executing as a ***root*** user. So remove the argument and execute your program.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Why do I need `--no-sandbox` to run Selenium Chromedriver even with admin privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699916/7429447)
- [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642913/7429447)

Comment: Thanks. I removed that part but still get this error: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
      (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install :

```
sudo apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils
```

And install chrome :

```
sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -fy install
```

It should work with : `-c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[disable-infobars, headless]"`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204160

It worked for me inside the docker container an on my machine too.